# Check Array exists in Array of Arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I personally like that title. My question is about the simplest and yet most secured way to find out if an array is contained in another array of arrays.

Here's my sample code to explaine a little bit more clear:

```
$container = array();
$array1 = array('A','B','C');
$container[] = $array1;

$array2 = array();
$array2[2] = 'C';
$array2[1] = 'B';
$array2[0] = 'A'; //now, the array is physically the same as $array1
if (in_array($array2,$container)) {
    echo "is inside";
}
```

If I have more complex array (no objects in it) which contains several keys which may get added in different order, but are *physically the same*, does `in_array` compare reliable, or do I have to check every key itself?

Comment: Can you give an example of what type of "complex" arrays you will encounter?

Comment: Please, keep in mind, that SO is not a forum and questions like "does in_array compare reliable?" and "do I have to check every key itself?" are not welcome here.

Comment: I thought about multidimensional arrays, for example, which will look the same but get built differently. For example in Java this makes a huge difference and you'll always have to care about this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You car use the native function PHP [array_walk_recursive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) with your custom callback.